# Show custom label in the taskbar of windows?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms

I'd like to show a custom label in my taskbar, for example the machine name. How could I accomplish this? Is this even possible without digging to deep into a windows api?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you want to create a ToolBar on the TaskBar. You need a DeskBand - like this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2219/Extending-Explorer-with-Band-Objects-using-NET-and